# Using web services to implement Android and IOS application

Tags: android, ios, web-services, mobile

I need to implement two geolocation applications: Android and IOS. Can I use web services for example REST to implement Android App in order to change later the presentation of my app from Android to IOS that can be useful for not write all code again to implement IOS app.

Thanks to help me

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `web service` will provide you data most probably in `xml` formate. Which may be stored in any collection (`Android list` and `IOS NSDictionay` ) . Webservice has nothing to do with the presentation of `IOS` or `Android`. It is just data. Only data base views may be affected.

Comment: What I want to say is to devise the application for 3-tiers: presentation , Business and DAO , for not repeat all that and use the same business you have to add web service in (xml or @ ). so you can just change the presentation (views) for example from JEE to PHP and the two other tries( business and Dao ) are not change. my question is  Can I apply The same way to implement the Andriod and IOS application

Comment: Yes, you need to implement webservice for both seprately . It will work for Android IOS or any other consumer which may be web or any other platform. Benefit of the Webservice is it can be used with any platform due to XML.   Dont forget to upvote

Comment: Thanks a lot Macrosoft-Dev